# Disabling eslint warning when using props inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, eslint

I am using the `useEffect` hook to call an action creator `props.getStoreItems`. I am getting the following eslint error

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props'. 
Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps.
```

Here is my code:

```
function GetStoreData(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const {storeType} = props;
    let url= null;

    if (storeType === 'episodeStore') {
      url = 'episode';
    } else if (storeType === 'characterStore') {
      url = 'character';
    };

    props.getStoreItems(url)
    // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []); 

  return null
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    storeItems: state.storeItems
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getStoreItems: getStoreItems }
)(GetStoreData);
```

The only props i pass in is a string which doesn't change

```
<GetStoreData storeType='episodeStore'/>
```

However, because I am using react-redux, and `mapStateToProps` the props of this component are changing whenever the action creator `props.getStoreItems` is called.

I can't think of a way to place props in the dependency array without causing an infinite loop. **In this situation is there any issues with me disabling the eslint error by using the following**?

```
// eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Comment: Maybe dumb question due to lack of context, but why are you using `mapStateToProps` plus `useEffect` instead of `useSelector`? (edit: possibly combining selectors using `reselect`)

Answer (score 0):

This warning is there because you are doing destructing `props` object.

So to remove that warning just use `props.storeType`.

But if you get a warning about that, just put that prop as dependency and put if statement that will check if it has a value:

```js
function GetStoreData(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.storeType) {
      let url = null;

      if (props.storeType === "episodeStore") {
        url = "episode";
      } else if (props.storeType === "characterStore") {
        url = "character";
      }

      props.getStoreItems(url);
      // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }
  }, [props.storeType]);

  return null;
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    storeItems: state.storeItems,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getStoreItems: getStoreItems })(
  GetStoreData
);
```